# Is the following a valid mathematical statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, logic, propositional-calculus

For all $f:\mathbb N\to\{1,2,3,\ldots,100\}$,
 If $f$ is a one to one correspondence,
 Then $f^{-1}(2)=3$

It seems as though this should not be a valid statement, since the implication fails to remain a statement when the hypothesis becomes false. This is because when $f$ is not one to one and onto, the syntax $f^{-1}(2)$ is undefined. So, the implication on a whole becomes undefined under such a condition. Is this true?

Comment: There are no such $f$, so the implication is correct. Every $6$-headed dog has composed an opera.

Comment: The non existence of such an f seems fine. However, the statement seems to turn weird due to the syntax used in the conclusion. Using the f inverse syntax hinges on the truth of the hypothesis. But, the hypothesis is known to be false.

Comment: @André Nicolas : I don't  think it's a good idea to use six-headed dogs and unicorns and the like as examples of vacuous truth.  It makes the whole concept seem unconnected with reality.  The example given in my answer below is far more practical.  It illustrates how the concept can have some utility. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No matter if it's weird or not: if there are no such $f$, then the conditional is vacuously true.

Comment: I understand the vacuous truth of the implication. But, for the implication to remain a statement, both the hypothesis and conclusion must have valid syntax.

Comment: @OnkarSinghGujral:   Hypothesis and conclusion are not written in a formal language. But something close to them could be, and there is no difficulty in making the translation be *syntactically* correct.

Comment: Is the use of f inverse images better than the use of f inverse in this case? Because f inverse images continue to be syntactically defined even when the hypothesis is false.

Comment: If f−1 is not defined, then  f−1(2)=3 is false.   f−1(2)=3 asserts a truth, which implies a partial definition of f-1 (note that I've used "f-1" here as one symbol for the inverse function of f).  So, we can't assume  f−1(2)=3 to possibly hold as true, because then f-1 becomes partially defined which it is not.

Comment: But if f inverse is not defined, does the sentence f inverse (2) =3 stay defined? I don't think so. Because if a term in the sentence isn't defined then the sentence is not defined as a whole and so it can't be a statement?

Comment: If you use the function notation "$f(\bullet)$" under the quantification of "For all $f\,:\,\cdots$", it is similarly not syntactically meaningful without the quantification. That does not mean that you should not use it, because it **is meaningful under the quantification**. This is not a well-formed first-order formula, but nobody uses pure first-order logic in practice.

Comment: @user21820 Pure first-order logic frequently gets used by automated theorem provers.  It also gets used by logic programming languages such a prolog and prolog programmers.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: When I say "nobody" I don't mean literally no one at all. Yet you're not quite right. Many common automated theorem provers like Coq don't use pure first-order logic but one branch of type theory. And I am willing to bet there is no automated theorem prover that uses **only** first-order logic that has more than 1000 users. Once you use the function notation you are **not** using first-order logic (unless all your functions are merely pre-defined predicates, since you cannot define functions in pure first-order logic!)

Answer (score 10):

An instructor asked the class whether all cell phones in the classroom are shut off.

If by some fluke, there are no cell phones in the classroom, then the answer is "yes".  "Yes" means there are no turned-on cell phones in the classroom.

Same thing here: there are **no** one-to-one correspondences from $\mathbb N$ into a set of only $100$ members; therefore, any statement you could make about such a correspondence is true.

Comment: But, does the use of f inverse not lead to a syntactical problem?

Comment: @OnkarSinghGujral : I'm afraid you'll need to explain that.  A one-to-one correspondence, in this context, would be a function that has an inverse. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes. But, when f assumes a value that is not a one to one correspondence, the predicate should still continue to become a statement. That does not seem to happen. Because f inverse(2) is rendered undefined due to the non invertibility of f. So, this should cause the entire statement to become undefined.

Comment: I guess the point that Onkar is trying to make is that since $f$ is not an invertible function, $f^{-1}(2) = 3$ is undefined, thus you have $\text{false} \implies \text{undefined}$, which some may consider to be unprovable, at least in a constructive logic, although classic nonlogic would not be concerned with it.

Comment: @OnkarSinghGujral: But if I'm right Michael is not interpreting the statement as a well-formed formula in classical logic. Rather, the conclusion of a conditional statement can syntactically depend on the condition. There is nothing wrong with that in ordinary mathematics. If one insists on making everything formal in ZFC for example, then one **cannot** use the notation "$f(x)$" for functions either! Note that such notation is meaningless if $f$ is not a function, but a quantified formula is supposed to have a well-formed subformula!

Answer (score 8):

The question is more complicated then a simple ex falso quodlibet. If the sequence of letters makes sense at all, then it is true, since there is no one-to-one function $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{1, \ldots, 100\}$.

However, it is not clear whether we are talking about a logical formula at all. For example $(\exists x: x\neq x)\Rightarrow (x+\forall)$ is not a valid formula, in particular it is not true, although it is of the form "false $\Rightarrow$ something".

The real problem is that $f^{-1}$ is a short-hand notation which goes beyond the realm of formal logic. We can declare that $f^{-1}(a)=b$ means that an inverse function exists and at $a$ this inverse function takes the value $b$. If we do so, then the statement becomes true. On the other hand we can view $^{-1}$ as a partial operation on the set of functions, i.e. the inverse function, if such a function exists, and gloppidyglopp otherwise. Then any statement involving $f^{-1}$ for a function $f$, which is not a bijection becomes neither true nor false, but undefined.

In this case this looks like (and probably is) nitpicking. However, there are real world examples where such a distinction does matter: What is the meaning of the statement $\lim a_n\neq 0$, if the limit does not exist? True, false, and undefined are all valid options.

The moral of the story is probably that when writing mathematics you should try to avoid ambiguities, and when reading mathematics, you should try to get the intended meaning, even if it differs from the formal statement.

Comment: You're right that there's more to the question than vacuous truth. Bertrand Russell in 'On Denoting' (Russell 1905) proposes an analysis how statements such as 'The present king of France is bald' are to be analyzed. Under the proposed analysis that sentence is analyzed as false, not as undefined or meaningless. This becomes clear, Russell shows, that once the underlying logical structure of the statement in question is revealed. For similar reasons, as I see $f^{-1}(2)=3$ as false---the analogy being between the two non-existent entities, i.e. the king and inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

"It seems as though this should not be a valid statement"

If it's not a valid statement, then either "f is a one to one correspondence" is true and "f−1(2)=3" is false, or both statements are false and "if p, then p" is false, where the truth value of the proposition "p" is false.  It is not the case that ""f is a one to one correspondence" is true and "f−1(2)=3" is false" holds.  It is also not the case that "if p, then p" is false, when the truth value of "p" is false.  If it were, then "if p, then p" would not qualify as a tautology.  Consequently, the statement is valid.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two ways to think about your question going back to the philosophy of logical reasoning:

(1) If we trust that classical propositional-logic is an adequate account of truth-preservation in mathematical reasoning then, looking at the truth-table for the material-conditional in classical propositional-logic, we see that the material-conditional is only false when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. $Every$ of the 3 remaining cases is going to make the material conditional true. In this case, we have a false antecedent so it doesn't matter what the truth-value of the consequent is - that is, it doesn't matter whether $f^{-1}(2) = 3$ or not since the antecedent is already false. This is the idea behind Michael Hardy's comment.

(2) If (1) is counter-intuitive, as it may very well be as it is counter-intuitive for many people, then consider that $p \rightarrow q$ is logically-equivalent classically-speaking to $\sim p \vee q$. Seen this way, either it is false that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3,...,100\}$ or it is true that $f^{-1}(2) = 3$. In our case, it is false that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3,...,100\}$, making $\sim p$ true, so the statement is valid.

Comment: Why the down-vote?